# Angular broadcast initialises too early

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to broadcast an event to another controller on page load. Although the controller that receives the broadcast is not initalised yet, therefore not reacting to the event.

```
app.controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', '$rootScope') {
    if(someVar) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("my-event");
    }
}]);

app.controller('ControllerTwo', ['$scope', '$rootScope') {
    $scope.$on("my-event", function() {
        console.log("Event hit!");
    })
}]);
```

My `ControllerOne` is the controller for my route, and my `ControllerTwo` is a controller for a view that is loaded via `ng-include` on that page.

Therefore, `ControllerOne` is called first, along with `ControllerTwo` being called later on when `ng-include` is initialised.

How can I initialise an event to `ControllerTwo` from `ControllerOne` without using a hacky approach such as `$timeout`? Is there a better way to approach this instead of using `$broadcast`?

Comment: Set your data in service from first controller and read that data in your second controller.

Comment: That way be the way to go @SaurabhAhuja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to approach this instead of using $broadcast?

I think the answer is probably 'yes', but it's hard to know without knowing what exactly you're broadcasting and why.

For example, at the moment, you're broadcasting event as soon as the controller runs. Is there a reason you can't just do the following (independent of `ControllerOne`):

```
app.controller('ControllerTwo', ['$scope', '$rootScope') {
  if(someVar) {
      console.log("Event hit!");
  }
}]);
```

I suspect you may suggest that `someVar` is only accessible in `ControllerOne`, at which point I'd suggest you make it accessible via a service and use that approach instead.

If you give a bit more context about exactly what you're trying to achieve I'll update the answer to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Hey Ed. Quite a complex project I'm working on, so would be a mission to post all the code! Basically, I have an `ng-include` that allows me to just include a widget on my page and it takes care of itself. Unfortunately, I would be unable to do any processing in `ControllerOne` since everything must be complete in `ControllerTwo`. Long story short, I am trying to broadcast an event to the `ControllerTwo` to let it know when to run a specific function.

Comment: Might just create a shared service and set a boolean value there from `ControllerOne` and then read it with `ControllerTwo` then. Might be the most elegant approach.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting doing anything in `ControllerOne` - simply moving the `someVar` check to `ControllerTwo`.

Comment: Oh okay, read that wrong sorry. The `someVar` variable must be kept inside of `ControllerOne` for specific reasons. Should have stated that sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could flip it around and `$emit` from the lower controller:

```
app.controller('ControllerOne', ['$scope', '$rootScope') {
    $scope.$on("checkForSomeVar", function(event, data) {
        if(someVar){
            data();
        }
    });
}]);
app.controller('ControllerTwo', ['$scope', '$rootScope') {
    $scope.$emit("checkForSomeVar", function() {
        console.log("Event hit!");
    });
}]);
```

But it really does sound like you should be using a service that you set in your main controller that your second controller also reads.